# How to set a details element to OPEN by default or via CSS

Tags: css, html

HTML5 adds two new elements that are useful for marking up a table of contents for an article: ***details*** and ***summary***.

The details element defaults to closed (hides everything except the summary element) and when clicked, it expands to reveal its contents. When it does this, it adds an "open" attribute to the details element.

I would like the element to default to open without having to add the open attribute to the markup. Is it possible to do this via CSS or would scripting have to come into play?

Example:

```
<details>
<summary>Table of Contents</summary>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="/2/">Body</a></li>
        <li><a href="/3/">Conclusion</a></li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

Comment: never tried this, but maybe `details[open] { display: block; }`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the "open" attribute?

Comment: @ToanNguyen in some cases (media queries) it may be useful to have the contents displayed by default. If a screen is flipped from horizontal to vertical, for example, you might want to force the contents open.

Answer (score 78):

You can add the `open` attribute into the `details` tag like this:

```html
<details open>
    <summary>Table of Contents</summary>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="/2/">Body</a></li>
        <li><a href="/3/">Conclusion</a></li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

The details will then be expanded by default.

Comment: The OP asked for a CSS or JS solution without requiring the HTML attribute.

Comment: @robrecord There is no solution using CSS because CSS is only for styling not for changing state of markup.

So the solution i am proposing is by adding open attribute. OP asking IF POSSIBLE, and if you read the title OPEN by default.

Comment: What about scripting with JS?

Comment: @robrecord See my answer for a JS solution.

Comment: Th OP even mentions the "open" attribute

Answer (score 3):

If you want a JS solution, you could give the details element an ID:

```
<details id="target-me">
 <summary>Table of Contents</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2/">Body</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3/">Conclusion</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

And then use the following JS:

```
document.getElementById("target-me").open = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in JavaScript

```js
const details = document.querySelector("details");
details.setAttribute("open", "");
```

Related to [html5 details tag open one by one javascript function working strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023608/html5-details-tag-open-one-by-one-javascript-function-working-strange)

Answer (score 0):

A use case for adjusting `<details>` tag's `open` attribute is for building responsive pages. For example, let it default open in desktop browsers but close in mobile phones. However, the attribute could not be set in CSS, so we have to use JavaScript to do media queries.

Code example:

```js
let mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
if(mql.matches) {
    details.open = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the alternative below it still has the ability to open and close but initially, it's opened and you can test that (I provided the output from my computer):

```
<div>
    <h3>Open</h3>
    <details open>
        <summary>Always open</summary>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </details>
</div>
```

check the photo of the output below:
[image]