# Can I set the "open" attribute on the HTML5 <details> responsively?

Tags: css, html, accessibility

I'm refactoring my site to use the HTML5 `details` tag, [as described here](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/), in order to improve accessibility.

This is my question: I know that I can add the `"open"` attribute to the `details` tag to ensure that the contents are displayed by default:

```
<details open>
  <summary>Show/Hide me</summary>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</details>
```

But is there a way I can set this responsively in CSS, so that the `open` attribute is automatically applied for pages with a width greater than 640px, and automatically *removed* for pages with a width below 640px?

Update: To be clear, I know I can do it with other CSS styling. I'm interested in understanding whether it's possible to do this with only the `open` attribute.

Comment: You can't change content of HTML attributes with CSS, but you can select these elements like this: `details[open] {`.

Comment: Similar question (but without any answer): [How to set a details element to OPEN by default or via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14286406/1591669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using pure responsive styling and only the `open` attribute.

But you can use media queries and other CSS styling to hide the element when the screen has the width you want. See: http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Comment: OK, so given that I want to show the contents on wider screens and hide them on smaller screens, the `details` attribute, with its automatic hiding and showing, might not actually be the best one to use. Would you agree? It sounds like I might be better off using manual CSS.

Comment: If I wanted a dropdown I would use CSS

Comment: Please select the answer if it answers your question and you found it useful.